# Manifest Merger Failed between the conflict of version

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

[image]

Error

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':chat-sdk-firebase-ui:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.  Manifest
>   merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value
>   value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35  is also present at
>   [com.android.support:design:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>   value=(26.1.0).   Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to
>    element at
>   manifestMerger5400804966500911997.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

build.gradle file is

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bhatti.chatsdk"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle  file(chatApp)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies{

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

 allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
}
```

gradle.properties file is

```
MIN_SDK = 16
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 26
ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION = 26
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = 26.0.2
GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION = 11.0.4
ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION = 26.0.2
```

Manifest.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bhatti.chatsdk">

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: have you checked my answer

Comment: Yes, I have Checked, but didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.2'
```

Instead of

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1'
```